# Rspec with Delayed Job - Testing message expectations

Tags: rspec, mocking, rspec2, stub

I have a demo method that runs some things through Delayed Job:

```
def test_dj
  User.delay.count
end
```

I want to set an expectation in the test that this is called. I know about should_receive, but since there's a chain here, stub_chain, to my knowledge, doesn't expect anything.

What's the best way to expect a chain to be called?

I ended up stubbing User.delay to return User, so that I could receive the expectation on #count. In parallel, I wrote a test to make sure jobs were received by DJ so that seems to cover it.

Comment: Please turn your answer into a real answer below. You can mark it as accepted after two days. That will make the question go away from the Unanswered Questions tab.

Comment: Actually I think your way is quite good